# How can I properly add input to a variable?

Tags: python, email, input

I'm constructing an email program for a project, and I need the program to accept mostly raw input. For example, in the "msg" section, I need the From:, the To: and where the body section is to be information obtained from an input() call.

```
   import smtplib
   fromaddr = input('Enter your email address you wish to send from: ')
   toaddrs  = input('Enter your destination email addresses: ')
   msg = msg = "\r\n".join([
   "From: foo.bar@gmail.com",
   "To: foo.bar@gmail.com",
   "Subject: Just a message",
   "",
   "Enter your body here."
   ])
   username = input('Enter username for smtp.gmail.com: ')
   password = input('Enter password for smtp.gmail.com: ')
   server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com:587')
   server.ehlo
   server.starttls()
   server.login(username,password)
   server.sendmail(fromaddr, toaddrs, msg)
   server.quit()
```

Comment: Are you using Python 2.x?

Comment: You should be able to extrapolate from what you are doing with username and password, then concatenate the msg together.  Are you having a specific problem?

Comment: I am using Python 3.3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `.format` to insert information into your message template:

```
fromaddr = input('Enter your email address you wish to send from: ')
msg = "From: {0}".format(fromaddr)
print(msg)  # will show 'From: hello@hello.com'
```

`.format` can be passed multiple arguments like so:

```
"Hello, {0}.  It's a {1} day outside.".format("Mr. Foo", "magical")
```

Does that clarify?